# Precision loss whilst inserting a double into MySQL through PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've run into this really annoying behavior and I want to know if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is intentional (and if so, why).

Whenever I have a variable in php (5.3) that is of type double and I want to insert it into the database (MYSQL 5.0) in a field that is of type double, the value always gets rounded down to 6 digits behind the point when I'm using PDO. So the below code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE someTable SET someDouble = :somePHPDouble;");
$number = 0.11124379542256;
$stmt->bindValue(':somePHPDouble', $number);
$stmt->execute();
```

Results in 0.111244 inserted into the db. But when I cast the variable to a string(!) in the binding expression like:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':somePHPDouble', (string)$number);
```

it inserts it properly as 0.11124379542256.

What is happening here ? I'm clueless. MySQL datatype of someDouble really is a double, and when inserting it through mysql console it just works. And the variable in php really is a double, so it seems to me that something goes wrong inside PDO.

Thanks in advance,
-CodePoet.

Comment: Did you try explicitly specifying PDO::PARAM_FLOAT? Like:
`$stmt->bindValue(':somePHPDouble', $number, PDO::PARAM_FLOAT);`

Comment: PDO does not specify a constant called PARAM_FLOAT. It is understood that when the client code omits the final parameter it indicated that the argument is to be treated as a float:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is neither intentional, nor are you doing something wrong. It seems to be a PHP bug.

According to [this bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48855), it has been fixed for PHP 5.2.11, but only recently for the 5.3 branch, so you might want to check your exact PHP version against the ones mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Henrik! I couldn't find that bug report, your GoogleFu > Mine.