# Why does mysql discarding float values?

Tags: php, html, mysql

everything was working fine but what happened now i can't say. Actually mysql does not storing any floating values and all other values such as integer, varchar etc are accepting. i am posting a portion of codes.

query in .php

```
$que_cinstructors = "
    INSERT INTO 
        course_instructors 
        ( usn, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9 )
    VALUES
        ( :usn, :i1, :i2, :i3, :i4, :i5, :i6, :i7, :i8, :i9 )";
$query_params3 = array( ':usn' => $_POST['usn'],
    ':i1' => $_POST['i1'],
    ':i2' => $_POST['i2'],
    ':i3' => $_POST['i3'],
    ':i4' => $_POST['i4'],
    ':i5' => $_POST['i5'], 
    ':i6' => $_POST['i6'],
    ':i7' => $_POST['i7'],
    ':i8' => $_POST['i8'],
    ':i9' => $_POST['i9']
);
$statement3 = $db->prepare($que_cinstructors);
$result3 = $statement3->execute($query_params3);

$que_ccredits = "
    INSERT INTO 
        course_credits 
        ( usn, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, total ) 
    VALUES ( :usn, :c1, :c2, :c3, :c4, :c5, :c6, :c7, :c8, :c9, :total )";
$query_params4 = array( ':usn' => $_POST['usn'],
    ':c1' => $_POST['c1'],
    ':c2' => $_POST['c2'],
    ':c3' => $_POST['c3'], 
    ':c4' => $_POST['c4'], 
    ':c5' => $_POST['c5'],
    ':c6' => $_POST['c6'], 
    ':c7' => $_POST['c7'],
    ':c8' => $_POST['c8'],
    ':c9' => $_POST['c9'],
    ':total' => $_POST['total']
);
$statement4 = $db->prepare($que_ccredits);
$result4 = $statement4->execute($query_params4);
```

from above two queries first one storing names, its fine. But second one is to store float values. Here i am getting usn from session variable. Insertion is fine for first one but for second one nothing is storing.

database from .sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course_instructors` (
`i_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`usn` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
`i1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`i2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`i3` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`i4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`i5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`i6` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`i7` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`i8` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`i9` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`i_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `usn` (`usn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course_credits` (
  `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usn` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `c1` float NOT NULL,
  `c2` float NOT NULL,
  `c3` float NOT NULL,
  `c4` float NOT NULL,
  `c5` float NOT NULL,
 `c6` float NOT NULL,
 `c7` float NOT NULL,
 `c8` float NOT NULL,
 `c9` float NOT NULL,
 `total` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `usn` (`usn`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Everything was working fine. i was working with some other parts of the project, today when i trying to submit then i faced this problem. It is making me crazy..Please help
And the text field names are correct.

Comment: Exactly how is it "discarding" Truncating the values? 3.1415 becomes 3? Completely incorrect values? (3.1415 becomes 17). You end up with null values? Are you **SURE** it's mysql doing this and not your code? Have you verified that the $_POST values are correct?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right decimal separator in your inputs?

Comment: Aren't there any warning while inserting the data? O_o

Comment: @marc.. i did not face such problem any more, but now i am trying from 8hrs. code is corect, it was working, discarding means it shows the old value that i inserted few days ago.

Comment: @sylvain... no warning

Comment: @DCoder...Yes such as 8, 8.2

Comment: is there any  browser issue or database

Comment: unique `usn`... do we need an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` - clause?

Comment: Are you trying to change the old data to new data? Are you using the same `usn`? Since you have `UNIQUE KEY \`usn\` (\`usn`)` you will either need to delete then reinsert or do `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`

Comment: It's most likely an issue in your code, not MySQL. Learn to debug your code by yourself. Dump the query and all the params before executing it, and analyse it for problems. Read up on your DB API's method of signaling errors and make use of it.

Comment: When you ping someone by typing their name, make sure you write what the little pop-up says. So to ping "Marc B" you need to put @MarcB. You can also use `Tab` to auto-complete.

Comment: @Wrikken.. since usn is unique so each time i try with new usn

Comment: @all...i also tried by deleting all data

Comment: @DCoder..Thanks for suggession...plz any other suggession

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to be doing a $stmt->bind_param().
That may well help although this post seems to contradict that and also mentions some buggy versions of PDO in various PHP releases.
However they do say use $stmt->bind_param() but  PDO::PARAM_STR can be used.

[Might be worth checking it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738074/precision-loss-whilst-inserting-a-double-into-mysql-through-pdo)

Aint is great, if you post some code using the old mysql_* code you get smothered in comments saying dont use it. 
When you use PDO you find its not bullet-proof.
Aint life a beach.